# Trying to simulate a simple micro inverter, Cant connect scope

Tags: inverter, matlab, simulink

I am trying to simulate a simple Micro inverter. Below is my Simulink Model :-

[image]

But somehow i am unable to connect Voltage Sensor to a scope. Even if i used a DC Source instead of Solar Cell.

What i have done is  :-

1. Connected two capacitors in parallel with the Solar Cell/ DC Voltage Source to distribute the voltage.
2. Using two Thyristors each with antiParallel diode and using Resistive Load, I am trying to measure Voltage and Current of the Load Branch.

Issue : -

Voltage Sensor and The Current Sensor i am using is from Simscape/Electrical Sensor Library, but i am unable to connect it to a Scope or a MUX. How do i read my load outputs?

I am fairly new to EE SE & Simulink, so if any additional info is needed, Please drop a comment.

Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need to explain how you are trying to do this and then ask an actual question ending with a '?'. (You're missing some other punctuation too.)

Comment: @Transistor I will update my post right away.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MathLab but your circuit looks strange. If the top rail on your schematic is the positive rail (as is the convention) then your diodes are shorting the positive rail to ground. The thyristors would then also be pointing the wrong way. Turn on component designations so that anyone trying to answer can say "D1" rather than "the diode in the top right corner of the schematic". Add in a link to the source of your circuit schematic if you didn't invent it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SimScape, the physical simulation engine within Simulink. This is apparent from the use of "Domain Styles" for the interconnections

- Electrical = Blue
- Gas = Purple
- Hydraulic = Mustard
- Magnetic = Purple
- Mechanical = Green
- Thermal = Orange
- Liquid (thermal) = Yellow
- Fluids  = L.Blue.

The 1st issue on your diagram is you are using the SimPowerSystems "PowerGUI"  This is the legacy electrical domain & this block is needed for the other "specialised technology" blocks.

You have already started using base SimScape and this is the "modern" method & as such you need to place a Solver block to the gnd reference

Your actual question: **How do i read my load outputs?**

Simulink has multiple simulation domains. The base domain is the **SIMULINK** domain & in this domain the classic scopes,mux, etc exist.

There is then the **PHYSICAL-SYSTEMS** domain. This is fundamental domain of simscape and this is where physical signals can cross physical domains.

Finally there are specific domains that are listed above.  Everything within the electrical domain can interact. Everything within the mechanical domain can interact. You cannot mix the two. The voltage sensor will create a signal in the PHYSICAL domain but this only facilitates interfacing with other simscape blocks. To interface with simulink you need a PS-Simulink converter

Below is an example of what you need todo

1. remove the PowerGUI
2. Attach the solver block to a node in the electrical domain (trace=BLUE)
3. Connect voltage sensor to the electrical domain (trace=BLUE)
4. Connect output of sensor to a PS-Simulink block (trace=BROWN)
5. Connect output of converter to scope (trace = BLACK)

[image]

Comment: Hey. Thanks that clearly explained a lot. I have upvoted your answer. But When i try to simulate for 1 sec or more the voltage output is kinda bit funny. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Your SIM or mine?

Comment: The one that you suggested... It won't show sine wave any more

Comment: You need to change the refinement factor from 1 to say... 100. It's a display issue not a simulation issue